# Notifications vibration are not working in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to implement notifications for android. I am able to trigger notifications but phone is not getting vibrated on notification. Here is sample code.

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel1";
            inboxStyle.addLine("Alex Faarborg  Check this out");
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(messagesCount + " new messages");
            inboxStyle.setSummaryText("Chat room");

            Notification summaryNotification =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentTitle("Chatroom has new messages")
                            .setContentText(messagesCount+" new messages")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                            .setGroupSummary(true)
                            .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationManager.notify(SUMMARY_ID, summaryNotification);
```

Comment: Make sure your phone isn't on mute btw

Comment: Try uninstalling the app and re-install again.

Comment: @Ctrl_see , Thanks for the suggestion. It is working now.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @SamChen, Thank you, It is working when I uninstalled and re-installed the app.

Answer (score 0):

try this
Vibrator customVibration = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); vibrator.vibrate(2000);

you can set vibrator object to notification object or notificationBuilder.
have fun :) !

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following custom vibrator.

```
 private fun customVibrate() {
  val mVibratePattern = longArrayOf(
    0, 400, 800, 600, 800, 800, 800, 1000, 400, 800, 600,
    800, 800, 800, 1000, 400, 800, 800, 600, 800, 800, 800, 1000, 400, 
 800
 )
  val v = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        v.vibrate(
            VibrationEffect.createWaveform(
                mVibratePattern,
                VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE
            )
        )
    } else { //deprecated in API 26
        v.vibrate(1000)
    }

}, 1000)
}
}
```